# How to add a custom object to the 'Objects' section of a xib file?

Tags: xcode5, xib

It is a followup question of [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439806/why-apples-sample-code-project-ikimageviewdemo-does-not-have-an-appdelegate-cla)

I want to know how I can add the `Controller` to the Objects section on the left hand side? I have tried context menu or the 'Edit' in the menu bar and I did not see relevant option.

It is what I see in the demo app:

[image]

You can see the `Controller` object in the Objects section (as selected in the image)

If I create a new project in xcode these days, it is what I see instead:

[image]

Xcode will put an `App Delegate` under `Objects` section.

In the other word, I want to know how I can modify the `Objects` section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer: I can drag a generic object from 'object library' to the 'interface builder dock' into as [shown here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles-general/CustomObject.html)